# Python pandas resample by day, group by value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart of total time per ticket per user per day, my `DataFrame` looks like this:

```
date_timestamp      ticket  time  user
23/03/2015 12:00:00 D-146   120   blgo
04/04/2015 12:00:00 D-173   15    blgo
29/04/2015 12:00:00 P-110   60    frle
29/04/2015 15:47:29 P-113   180   chki
29/04/2015 15:47:55 P-113   30    chki
30/04/2015 12:00:00 P-108   240   frle
30/04/2015 12:00:00 P-116   120   hahe
30/04/2015 13:46:25 P-116   240   hahe
01/05/2015 09:20:48 P-113   120   frle
01/05/2015 09:39:13 P-107   45    frle
```

Each bar on the chart would represent one user on one day - the height of the bar would represent the total time spent that day in minutes, and would be divided proportionally by the amount of time that the user had logged on each ticket that day.

I know that I can get total time per day per user using the following:

```
df[(df.user == 'blgo')]['time'].resample('B',how='sum').fillna(0)
```

I also know that I can group the dataframe by ticket like so:

```
df2=df['time'].groupby(df['ticket'])
```

Presumably, to achieve my goal, I need a dataframe for each user, with days on the index, tickets as columns, and each cell would be the total time logged on that ticket on that day.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the _fraction_ of time each user spent on a given ticket on a given day to be represented, or the _time_?  (For instance, in your example user 'frle' somehow managed to spend 54 hours on P-108 on 30/04/2015 while user 'hahe' spent six hours on P-116 that day; should those both be represented as "100% of users' time" or scaled to absolute hours?)

Comment: I want *time* - in some instances, that may lead to the daily total being over 24hrs per day, but that's alright. Nevertheless, I'll amend the table because that could be confusing for some people, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to make a few additional tweaks depending on precisely how you want to handle days with no contributions from a particular user, but the basic structure you want is a [pivot table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html). Starting from your dataframe:

```
df.reset_index()
df['date'] = df['date_timestamp'].dt.date
del df['date_timestamp']
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['date', 'user'], columns=['ticket'], values='time', aggfunc=np.sum)
df2.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
df2.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image]

Comment: That's it - thank you so much! I had heard of pivot tables before but never used one. I understand them now. Unfortunately, my original dataset has 5,000 rows and many users, so attempting the code above crashes my machine, but of course that's something that I have to contend with. It works perfectly when I constrict it to just one user, however. By the way, presumably the 5th and 6th line should start with `df2`?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the typos.  Subsetting by day might help if your original dataset is too large for your machine.